# MOSFET biasing and Rg value

Tags: mosfet

I have a doubt and can't find relevant information in books/internet about setting a suitable value of Rg resistance during MOSFET biasing using a large drain-to-gate feedback
resistance. Here is a visualization of the problem:

[image: MOSFET biasing]

The current of Rg is 0 amperes, meaning that we cannot use Ohm's law here. But as far as I understand, the voltage at the gate is the same as drain Vd (the upper half of the MOSFET). It seems a bit not very intuitive to me, but I will get it.

Now, the common knowledge says that the value of Rg must be "sufficiently large" around some Mega Ohms, but still, I had not seen any formula or a way to find its minimum value or something. Is there a formal way to determine it resistance, or just say that it should be "large" around some Mega Ohms?

Comment: But that is exactly what Ohm's law says: since no current flows through Rg, the voltage over it is 0, so Vg = Vd. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *as far as I understand, the voltage at the gate is the same as drain Vd*

In your circuit that is correct because the gate to source resistance can be massive and, that means virtually no DC current passes through \$R_G\$.

> *I had not seen any formula or a way to find its minimum value*

Its minimum value depends on what you are trying to use the MOSFET for i.e. what is the application you are trying to fulfil. In some applications the minimum value could be zero. In other applications it could be tens of mega ohm. It's application dependent.

> *Is there a formal way to determine it resistance, or just say that it
> should be "large" around some Mega Ohms?*

Yes, but it's **application dependent**.

Comment: Thank you. It should work with DC of VDD around 3~5 Volts. The resistance of Rd is around some Kilo Ohms. Any formula, or a way to derive a formula?

Comment: @KrtekUser the formula is totally dependent on your target application. You haven't specified an application so there's nothing I can propose to you. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: It should be related to transistor amplifiers as an application

Comment: Not enough to go on. To calculate an appropriate value requires knowledge of circuit gain, expected bandwidth, MOSFET D-G capacitance and signal source impedance. You can't generalize this. You have to have a specific target circuit (and performance) in mind.

Comment: Ok. Probably this goes far beyond my question. Thanks.

Comment: @KrtekUser maybe consider beginning a new question with the proposed schematic for the amplifier and attract also others into answering. Leave me a link to the question please.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate the gain of this amplifier, it would come out to be:
$$
A_v = \frac{(1-g_mR_G)R_D}{R_G+R_D}
$$
Assuming that \$R_G >> R_D\$, \$A_v = -g_mR_D\$. Thus, keeping \$R_G\$ much larger (for example, \$R_G = 10\times R_D\$) than \$R_D\$ ensures that the amplifier gain is not affected by it.